# Python: Getting KeyError while executing forcast( ) in statsmodel's holtwinters function

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

I'm trying to get time series prediction using the following code.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing as HWES

#read the data file. the date column is expected to be in the mm-dd-yyyy format.
df_train_y = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne_train_output)
df_train_y.index.freq = 'd'

df_test_y = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne_test_output)
df_test_y.index.freq = 'd'

#plot the data
df_train_y.plot()
plt.show()


#build and train the model on the training data
model = HWES(df_train_y, seasonal_periods=144, trend='add', seasonal='add')
fitted = model.fit(optimized=True, use_brute=True)

#print out the training summary
print(fitted.summary())

#create an out of sample forcast for the next 12 steps beyond the final data point in the training data set
trend_forecast = fitted.forecast(steps= 157200)
```

And my data looks like this:

```
df_train_y >>

    y_train
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
... ...
366755  65
366756  66
366757  63
366758  65
366759  68
```

When I'm executing the above code on my data, I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-66fe58a542ec> in <module>()
     23 
     24 #create an out of sample forcast for the next 12 steps beyond the final data point in the training data set
---> 25 trend_forecast = fitted.forecast(steps= '157200')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py in forecast(self, steps)
    344         try:
    345             freq = getattr(self.model._index, 'freq', 1)
--> 346             start = self.model._index[-1] + freq
    347             end = self.model._index[-1] + steps * freq
    348             return self.model.predict(self.params, start=start, end=end)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

So I tried to check the type of operands in the line 346,
upon running `type(fitted.model._index[-1])` I'm getting `int`; also I edited the code in `holtwinters.py` by typecasting all operands to `int` using `int()` but still the error persists.

I have reported this issue in the github repo for statsmodels [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7565).
And asked same question in datascience stackexchange, but got nothing. [DS Stackexchange question link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97738/getting-keyerror-while-executing-forcast-in-statsmodels-holtwinters-function)

Comment: what is the dtype of df_train_y? have you taken care of NaNs?

Comment: The solution is to not set `.freq`.  Leave this as `None`.